# very difficult mysql query - random order on two tables

Tags: mysql

Consider this classical setup:

`entry` table:
id (int, PK)
title (varchar 255)

`entry_category` table:
entry_id (int)
category_id (int)

`category` table:
id (int, PK)
title (varchar 255)

Which basically means entries can be in one or more categories (the `entry_category` table is used as MM/join table)

Now I need to query 6 unique categorys along with 1 unique entries from these categories by RANDOM!

EDIT: **To clarify: the purpose of this is to display 6 random categories with 1 random entry per category**.

A *correct* result set would look like this:

```
category_id   entry_id     
10            200 
20            300
30            400
40            500
50            600
60            700
```

This would be incorrect as there are duplicates in the `category_id` column:

```
category_id  entry_id
10           300
20           300
...
```

And this is incorrect as there are duplicates  in the `member_id` column:

```
category_id  entry_id     
20           300
20           400
...
```

---

How can I query this?

If I use this simple query with order by rand, the result contains duplicated rows:

```
select c.id, e.id
from category c    
inner join entry_category ec on ec.category_id = c.id
inner join entry e on e.id = ec.entry_id
group by c.id
order by rand()
```

Performance is at the moment not the most important factor, but I would need a reliably working query for this, and the above is pretty much useless and does not do what I want at all.

EDIT: as an aside, the above query is no better when using `select distinct ...` and leaving out the `group by`. This includes duplicate rows as `distinct` only makes sure that the combinations of `c.id` and `e.id` are unique.

---

EDIT: **one solution** I found, but probably slow as hell on larger datasets:

```
select t1.e_id, t2.c_id
from (select e.id as e_id from entry e order by rand()) t1
inner join (select ec.entry_id as e_id, ec.category_id as c_id from entry_category ec group by e_id order by rand()) t2 on t2.e_id = t1.e_id
group by t2.c_id
order by rand()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  category_id, entity_id
FROM    (
        SELECT  category_id,
                @ce :=
                (
                SELECT  entity_id
                FROM    category_entity cei
                WHERE   cei.category_id = ced.category_id
                        AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(entity_id, @r)
                ORDER BY
                        RAND()
                LIMIT 1
                ) AS entity_id,
                (
                SELECT  @r := CAST(CONCAT_WS(',', @r, @ce) AS CHAR)
                )
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @r := ''
                ) vars,
                (
                SELECT  DISTINCT category_id
                FROM    category_entity
                ORDER BY
                        RAND()
                LIMIT 15
                ) ced
       ) q
WHERE  entity_id IS NOT NULL
LIMIT  6
```

This solution is not a piece of code I'd be proud of, since it relies on black magic of session variables in `MySQL` to keep the recursion stack. However, it works.

Also it's not perfectly random and can in fact yield less than `6` values (if `entity_id`'s duplicate across the categories too often). In this case, you can increase the value of `15` in the innermost query.

Create a unique index or a `PRIMARY KEY` on `category_entity (category_id, entity_id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: This IS black magic. Thank you very much for your work, I will give it a try. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the good way to do this is to pick 6 distinct values from each set, shuffle each list of values (each list individually), and then glue the lists together into a two-column result.

To randomize which six you get, shuffle the *entire* list of each type of value, and grab the first six.

Comment: could you tell me more about your approach? Would you do two queries? First selecting random categories, then selecting random entries matching for these categories?

Comment: Well I'm not a mysql expert so I'm not exactly sure how you'd do it there. The idea is to shuffle the lists of distinct values and then grab what you need from each.  That way you know you don't have duplicates, and you know that they're randomly selected. It's like picking 6 cards from each of two shuffled decks.

Comment: You could always just select the first six from one query on one table (ordered by rand()) and then the first six from the second table, also randomly ordered, and then you've got your two lists (from two separate queries). How to get a two-column result from SQL directly is the tricky part.

Comment: Not entirely sure how this works, I mean, if I select 6 random entries and 6 random categories - how should I make sure that the entries relate to the categories?

Comment: Well now you didn't say you needed them to be **related** - you just said "six unique entries along with six unique categories."

Comment: Heh, of course they need to be related, otherwise it would be very easy, but rather pointless. I made I mistake in the description of my question, so if you have any other ideas, it would be great.

Comment: Well then if you just select "id" from the "entry" table and join to the entry_category table, ordered randomly, you can just read through the result set and only keep rows that fit the "no duplicates" rule for the category id.